# How to multiply with percentage in android

Tags: android

I have total question 40 and Correct_Answer = 36 and Incorrect_Answer = 4.

How can i multiply it to percentage in android programe.

The result of mind alway display with 0.0%

Code:

```
int total_score = (Correct_Answer/40)*0.01);

Txt_Total_Score.setText(Integer.toString(total_score + "%"));
```

Comment: In place of `0.01`, it should be `100`. Try with that. and it sould be `Integer.toString(total_score) + "%"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of integer use float. And also multiply with 100.

```
float total_score = ((float)Correct_Answer/40)*100);
Txt_Total_Score.setText(Float.toString(total_score + "%"));
```

Comment: Note that using a float instead of an integer for the `total_score` variable is not strictly required if he needs only integer values.

Answer (score 2):

you are performing an integer division between two integer where the divisor is grater than the dividend, and since 36/40 will give you 0.9, and total score is a int, the decimal part is stripped away. So you have to promote one from dividend and divisor to float performing a cast:

int the last row, since you are concatening a String with a integer, you will get alread a String as result (Integer.toString is useless)

```
float correctAnswerFloat = (float)Correct_Answer / 40 ;
int total_score = (int )( correctAnswerFloat * 100 );
Txt_Total_Score.setText(total_score + " %"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

```
float total_score = ((float)Correct_Answer * 100 / 40); // Edited with information from comments :)

Txt_Total_Score.setText(Float.toString(total_score) + "%");
```

Comment: The int is always going to return 0. Make it `Correct_Answer*100/40`

Comment: He should also use a floating point division. If `Correct_Answer` is an integer the result will always be zero.

Comment: I had no idea that `int` would return zero. I used to think that the part before the decimal would be returned. Thanks.

Comment: The thing is `int` hacks off the decimal part after EVERY operation. So `Correct_Answer/40` will be 0 unless `Correct_Answer>40`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
int total_score = (Correct_Answer*100)/40;
```

In what you do, the parenthesis give a result of 0 `int` hacks of decimal places. So multiply by 100 first and then divide by the total questions.